# Cannot create database in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database

I have an application on Visual Studio 2010, Visual c#. I have created a database for the application and it used to ran just fine. But today when I ran my application, the database wasn't working. I deleted the `.mdf` file and tried to create a new one, but a get this error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
>   connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured
>   to allow remote connection.(provider:SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I don't know what to do in order to be able to create a database again, since I don't know that happened in the first place to disable it.

Comment: Are you sure the database instance is running?

Comment: In your start menu, find the SQL Configuration Manager

Comment: I only have SQL Configuration Manager Installed

Comment: Open up SQL Server Configuration Manager. With that you can see if your instance is stop or running

Comment: It says that it failed.

Comment: Right click it, and restart it.

Comment: can't. When I right click it, there only an option for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I can think of...

1. Is [SQL Server installed/up and running](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366339.aspx)?
2. Do you already have a non-user instance database named the same thing in SQL Server?
3. Is your connection string set up properly?

Comment: when I click on the SQL Server Services, I get an error that the call failed

Comment: Try rebooting the computer. I've had funky stuff happen with SQL Server before where a reboot fixed it. If that doesn't work, check to make sure SQL Server is still installed by going into the Control Panel and checking the list of programs in Uninstall Programs. It is possible to uninstall SQL Server but have all the other tools still present. Did you upgrade or make any changes to permissions recently?

Comment: No clue. You'd have to look at your Windows Application logs to see what caused the service to shut down.